# Exporting .o & binary files to bin folders

Tags: gcc, makefile

My question is a real simple one I just want to export everything that is not source code to a bin folder but all the answers that I find seem to have either loose chunks of complex makefile code without any indication to where to place it or very complex makefiles in general. I have no experience with make files and the documentation seems extremely poor so if one can give me the simplest answer to this problem I'd be very happy.

```
#
#   Makefile for 2INC0 Interprocess Communication
#
#   (c) Fontys 2010, Joris Geurts
#
BIN=./bin/

BINARIES = $(BIN)prime

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -c
LDLIBS = -lrt -lX11


%.o: %.c 
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $(BIN)$@

all:    $(BINARIES)

clean:
    rm -f *.o $(BINARIES)

prime: prime.o 

prime.o: prime.c prime.h
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this modification:

```
$(BIN)%.o: %.c 
   $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(BIN)prime: $(BIN)prime.o 

$(BIN)prime.o: prime.h
```

Answer (score 0):

The (almost universally followed) convention is to have a special target `install` that unconditionally copies all of the required files from the build tree into place.  That place is usually configurable with a variable.

That way, you can always just remove the build tree after you're done building and installing.

So if all of the files you need to copy are executables, you get something like this:

```
DESTDIR = /usr/local

OBJS = $(*.c:%c=%.o)
EXES = $(OBJS:%.o=)

install: $(EXES)        
    cp -p $+ $(DESTDIR/bin/
```

(beware: untested).  Which version of which `make` are you using?